# Path in Ubuntu Core

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have a basic question:

I'm running Ubuntu Core in a Raspberry, but I am unsure about the directory structure. In my understanding, Ubuntu Core uses environments (snaps) where programs are installed. One of them is "classic". Accessing via SSH I have the following:

`(classic)rubens@localhost:~$`

However, cd /home/rubens/classic does not exist.

As in Anaconda, where we have `/home/rubens/anaconda3/tensorflow` ... etc I'm wondering what is the path in Ubuntu Core.

I cannot infer the answer via `ls -lap`